# Acrobat SDK: How to get events and write event handlers in c#

Tags: c#, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am trying out to get events from a pdf doc and handle it in my c# code with the samples that come with Acrobat-SDK.

I am yet to understand how I can do it. I am yet to discover the class that provides me the events. All the classes currently expose methods only. It might be that I am missing something for sure.

Can somebody help?

My use case is:

1. the user will open a pdf doc and my application (or my app can trigger opening the pdf doc)
2. when the user selects some text from the pdf doc, my app should get the event
3. My event can handle the selection and get the selected text.
4. Put a bookmark on the selection in the pdf doc (with additional attributes)
5. the pdf doc retains such bookmarks when the pdf is saved.
6. bookmarks in the pdf should be available for edit.
7. A different app/code should be able to parse and retrieve these bookmarks along with the additional attributes of the bookmark.

I hope, I have not asked too much.

Comment: Seems very little footfall on Acrobat questions!